# Product URL take current store name in Magento multistore

Tags: php, magento

I have one website & three store with different theme:

Furniture,
Jewellery,
Cloth

Multistore functionality works perfect & three store share the same cart too.

I have 'Add Store Code to Urls' set to 'YES'.

The problem is that, when i go to cart page or recently viewed product or compared product(in short all the places where product link is there to jump to product) the url contail the storecode of current store not the storecode for the product it belongs to.

For Example,
I added one product from each store to cart, so cart have total 3 product from three different store. When i open cart from furniture store & click on the product from cloth & jewellery store the url is like http://example.com/**furniture**/productname.html

What I need is from whole site when user click on product it will contain that product's store to URL everytime not the current store. So it will open in correct theme with right logo.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the following theme file within the cart:

```
/app/design/frontend/[your theme]/default/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

There is a line which gets the product URL:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?></a>
```

And add the suffix option to it as such:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() . $this->getProductUrlSuffix()?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?></a>
```